# Binary to Decimal with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, binary, decimal

I am trying to convert a binary number (constructed from an array with 0's and 1's) to a decimal value. Every time I run the program, the decimal value is way off. I am wondering if my code for the decimal inside the loop might be wrong? Here's what I have so far:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decimal = 0;
        int[] arrayNums = new int[8];
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            arrayNums[i] = (int)(Math.random()*2);
            System.out.print(arrayNums[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            for(int j=7; j>=0; j--) {
                decimal += arrayNums[i]*(int)Math.pow(2,j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The decimal value is: " + decimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: _""the decimal value is way off_ - please show some examples of input and output, and explain what you have done to debug the code. Did you step through it in your IDE debugger?

Comment: You can convert your array to a string and use `Integer.parseInt(string, 2)`. This will also convert your binary number to a decimal number. E.g. `String string = Arrays.stream(arrayNums).boxed().map(i -> Integer.toString(i)).collect(Collectors.joining())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's keep your existing code and try to fix it (I'm also going to clean up your syntax a bit for good code style).

As of now, your for-loop is populating your array this way, where each list entry is each iteration of the loop:

1. `[0, , , , , , , ]`
2. `[0,1, , , , , , ]`
3. `...`
4. `...`
5. `...`
6. `...`
7. `...`
8. `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]`

Remember, when `i=0`, we are at the **most significant** bit, meaning it has the decimal value 128.

When you're reading this array with the second for-loop, you're actually starting at the most significant bit but raising it to the 0th power, instead of the 7th power.
This is why your answers are wrong. Let's instead raise it to the `7-i` power.

```
class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = 0;
        int decimal = 0;
        int[] arrayNums = new int[8];
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            arrayNums[i] = (int)(Math.random()*2);
            System.out.print(arrayNums[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            decimal += arrayNums[i]*(int)Math.pow(2,7-i);

        }
        System.out.println("\nThe decimal value is: "+decimal);
    }
}
```

ps.
The `\n` is just an escape character that tells the console window to print a new line. This is just for formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating the loop to convert. Try it like this. Multiply the previous value in decimal by 2, then add the bit.  Each multiplication shifts the value left by 1 bit.  You don't need the Math.pow() method since it works automatically as you `"shift"` the value.  I suggest you try this on paper to see how it works to ensure you understand it.

```
int decimal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    decimal = decimal * 2 + arrayNums[i];
}
```